# Given a column vector, can we add columns, continuously dependent on the given one, to get an invertible matrix?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-topology, fibration

Given a vector $x$ in the $n=6$-dimensional Euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^n$, do there exist $n-1$ continuous functions $f_1$ to $f_{n-1}$ such that the matrix $$(x,f_1(x), … ,f_{n-1}(x))$$
is invertible for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am aware of the results of

T. Wazewski,
Sur les matrices dont les elements sont des fonctions
continues.
Composito Mathematica, tome 2 (1935), p. 63-68

B Eckmann,
Mathematical survey lectures 1943-2004.
Springer 2006.

There is no topological obstruction for $n=6$ whereas there is for $n$ odd. I know the solution for $n=2$ and $4$. It is based on permutations with appropriate signs in order to make $f_i(x)$ orthogonal to $x$. This does not work for $n=6$. Hence the question for $n=6$ and even larger $n=8$, …

Comment: You should restrict $x$ to be nonzero.

Comment: Isn't "there is no topological obstruction" in itself a claim that such continuous functions do exist? So your real question must be about finding a nice _explicit_ description of such a set of functions, rather than simply an existence proof.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "there is no topological obstruction"? Sure, the Euler characteristic is zero for an odd sphere, but that only gives you the first $f_1$, you still need the rest. As Eric Wofsey's answer shows, there *is* a topological obstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting $x$ to the unit sphere and projecting all the vectors $f_i(x)$ onto the orthogonal complement of $x$, this is equivalent to asking whether the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is parallelizable (since the $f_i(x)$ will be a basis for the tangent space at $x$ for each $x\in S^{n-1}$).  By a famous deep theorem (see, for instance, section 2.3 of [these notes](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) by Allen Hatcher), the only parallelizable spheres are $S^0$, $S^1$, $S^3$, and $S^7$.  In particular, $S^5$ is not parallelizable, so this is impossible in your case.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean that the systematic permute-and-flip-signs strategy that seems to work well for $n=2,4,8$ doesn't generalize to $n=16$?

Comment: I'm not sure what the "systematic permute-and-flip-signs strategy" is, but if it really is systematic, I would bet it corresponds to the inductive [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) of larger and larger division algebras, which breaks down because the algebras have less and less regularity properties, and finally at $n=16$ fail to be division algebras.

Comment: x @Eric: Hmm, good point. Actually what I had in mind does, in hindsight, seem to be more or less isomorphic to the Cayley-Dickson construction. Would also explain why I seem to have trouble converting my handwavy intuition that it should work into an actual argument. :-)